# New Google spreadsheet onEdit set focus to a cell not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I type a ID in column1, I am trying to get the some text related to that ID and show in column2 and set the focus to column3. This worked perfectly so far and the code is given below. Now I migrated to the new google spread sheet and the focus part is not working. As per the below link this feature is now removed. Is there any other way to do this please?

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  //Removed some other code for clarity.

  RangeTest();
}



function RangeTest()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var nextTarget = ss.getRange(2, 2);
   ss.setActiveRange(nextTarget);   
   Logger.log("Focus Set");
}
```

[<sheet>.setActiveRange() seems to have stopped working with onOpen trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300587/sheet-setactiverange-seems-to-have-stopped-working-with-onopen-trigger)

[Google Script - OnEdit problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333232/google-script-onedit-problems)

[Google Sheets getActiveRange on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702386/google-sheets-getactiverange-on-change)

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger setActiveRange from an onEdit trigger [since April 17 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_2014)

Comment: Do you know any alternative way pls?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a simple onEdit trigger use an installable onEdit trigger.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable